# How insert line break into <h3> with css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, line-breaks

```
<h3 class="views-field-title clickable-link">
    <a href="/article/elektro-elektroniker-energie">
       Elektro Rider Electrotechniker Energy and Smarhome Technics 
    </a>
</h3>
```

This is the HTML code that I get from a view on a Drupal webpage. I can not edit it but I can apply CSS.(I have just frontend access) When I minimize the page, this title doesn't shorten itself automatically, therefore, I am trying to insert a line break and make it.

Elektro Rider Electrotechniker 
Energy and Smarhome Technics

Looks like this. Is it possible to do it with CSS? or jquery?

Not: If I could edit the HTML then I would add another span class

```
Elektro Rider Electrotechniker <span class="new">Energy and Smarhome Technics<span/>
```

and with CSS easily could insert a line break.

Comment: it didnt work...

Comment: Basically you can't with CSS. Your only option would be to subsiture your existing spaces for `non-breaking spaces` except where you want the text to break. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/goQKKL

Comment: can you try `h3 { width: 100vh; }`?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you don't have a white space: nowrap. In case you have it change it nowrap for normal. Even so, the text would be adapted to the screen.

Another option would be to use a media query with a max-width on the h3, to force the line break just where you want it. The "white-space: nowrap;" would make this useless, so check that the tags "h3" and "a" do not have this property.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  h3 {
    max-width: 300px;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k9nbaf14/